# API to install driver from driverstore

Tags: windows, winapi, driver, modem

Is there any APIs available to install the driver for my device say for example (PNPC031)  from the driverstore or from the inf folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Triggering plug-and-play detection for devices should install the driver for your device from the inf directory/driver store - if it finds a matching driver. 
Check out the CM_Reenumerate_DevNode_Ex API:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539766(v=vs.85).aspx

If you know the path of your INF file you can install it with the Setup API:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377398(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I dont know, if this it exactly you want, but for install driver from inf file may use [ADVAPACK.DLL API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752070%28v=vs.85%29).